# jpgraph: display range in line chart

Tags: jpgraph

Is it possible to display a transparent color for a special range in a line chart?

For example I want to show temperature as a line chart. There are normally values between 22 and 25°C. I want to show a range between 23 and 24°C with a transparent green. Values above or below this range don't have such a transparent background.

I hope you understand what I mean...

```
$graph = new Graph(900,300);
$graph->SetScale("lin");

$p1 = new LinePlot($datay);
$graph->Add($p1);
$p1->SetColor("#6495ED");
$p1->SetLegend('°C');

$sline = new PlotLine(HORIZONTAL,23,'green'); 
$graph->Add($sline);

$sline = new PlotLine(HORIZONTAL,24,'green'); 
$graph->Add($sline);

$graph->Stroke();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can do that:

```
// Add band
$band = new PlotBand(HORIZONTAL,BAND_SOLID,23,24,'green');
$band->ShowFrame(false);
$graph->AddBand($band);
```